# AlertDialog is not announcing the message in android

Tags: android, talkback

When I turn on the Talkback feature in a Android device, when alert dialog is shown, it only announces only the Title and not the message. I am looking to also announce the Message (Do you want to delete ?) along with the Title (Delete). I am clueless on how this can be done.

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, 0);
                    builder.setTitle(R.string.dialog_title)
                            .setMessage(R.string.dialog_message)
                            .setPositiveButton(R.string.delete_text,
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                              //op
                                        }
                                    })
                            .setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_cancel_button_content_description,
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            // no op
                                        }
                                    })
                            .setCancelable(true);
                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
```

Strings.xml :

```
<string name="dialog_title" comment="delete button."><b>Delete</b></string>
<string name="dialog_message" comment="confirmation dialog of delete button.">Do you sure you want to delete?</string>
```

Comment: Can you show us your `strings.xml`? Do you have multiple `strings.xml`? It seems like `R.string.delete_text` is an empty string. You can try this via debugging, assign a string's value to `getString(R.string.dialog_message)` and check in debug-time (or using `Log` functions to see whether or not it's returning empty or null content

Comment: I have updated my post with strings.xml. The Alert Dialog displays the strings in the Alert Dialog, but talkback is not announcing the message string, it only announces the title string.

Comment: Not sure, how this title is read by the accessibility feature